# Akka - Fixed thread pool for Blocking Operations - Blocking Dispatcher

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

I have configured a dispatcher for the blocking operations that my application is going to execute as shown below:

```
engine {
  blocking-io-dispatcher {
     type = Dispatcher
     executor = "thread-pool-executor"
     thread-pool-executor {
       fixed-pool-size = 3
     }
       throughput = 1
  }
}
```

However, I can see in the logs that every 5 seconds more than 3 threads are processing the requests, (threads 6,16,5,7,15)

**Console Output:**

system-engine.blocking-io-dispatcher-6
system-engine.blocking-io-dispatcher-16
system-engine.blocking-io-dispatcher-5
system-engine.blocking-io-dispatcher-7
system-engine.blocking-io-dispatcher-15

Please find the code below:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import java.util.Date
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRouter
import akka.routing.DefaultResizer

class SendPushNotificationActor extends Actor {
   def receive = {
      case SendPushNotificationMessage(message) => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName)
      // Simulate blocking operation which takes 5 seconds to send the push notification message
      Thread.sleep(5000)
    }
  }
}

object SendPushNotificationTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("system")

    val sendPushNotificationActor = system.actorOf(Props[SendPushNotificationActor].withDispatcher("engine.blocking-io-dispatcher")
  .withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances = 5)))

    for (i <- 1.to(100)) {
      sendPushNotificationActor ! SendPushNotificationMessage("Push Notification Message")
    }
  }
}

case class SendPushNotificationMessage(message: String)
```

Any help to know how to make the pool fixed would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code that utilized the `Dispatcher`?

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil I Have added all the information, thank you for your help and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Threads in the pool could die due to some reason and in that case new threads could be spawned immediately to replace the dead ones and have the pool maintain the fixed size. New threads were given incremented ID, which was what you saw in the log file. The size of the thread pool is definitely fixed.